# Four dimensional integral calculation

Tags: integration

I do some calculation in QED, but I can not calculate such integral
$$
I(a_1,a_2,m_1,m_2)=\int\frac{ d\mathbf{x} d\mathbf{y}}{(1+\mathbf{x}^2)(1+\mathbf{y}^2)((\mathbf{x}+a_1 \mathbf{y})^2+m^2_1)((\mathbf{x}+a_2 \mathbf{y})^2+m^2_2)}
$$
where $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ are two dimensional vectors.
The integration is performed over the whole space.
It is possible to calculate such integrals? If yes, how I can  do it?

Comment: Are the first $1+x^2$ and $1+y^2$ parts different variables from the $x+a_1y$ and similar parts?

Comment: If so, they can be considered as constants of integration...

Comment: $x^2=\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}$

Comment: Should the second factor in the denominator be $(1+\mathbf{y}^2)$? That would make the integral symmetric in $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ (after scaling)...

Comment: Yes. I corrected the mistake